# On local PC IIS and Browser maxes out CPU with large result set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I just upgraded to VS 2013 and also started a new MVC project, and am being faced with 99% CPU usage for a couple minutes by IIS while debugging on my local PC.  (Happens in both Release and Debug mode) I just realized that the problem is proportional to the number of lines returned by by Linq Query.  If I use Take(1) or Take(10) it's fine.  If I use Take(100) the problem occurs.

Here is my actionresult (with private info altered):

```
    public ActionResult Summary(string daystoshow, DateTime? day = null)
    {
        int daysToShow = daystoshow.ToSafeInt();
        if (daysToShow < 1) daysToShow = 2;
        if (day == null) day = Convert.ToDateTime("4/14/2014");  
        SummaryViewModel m = new SummaryViewModel();
        string warnings = "";
        var ef1 = new carshowEntities();

        DateTime dayAtMidnight = Convert.ToDateTime(((DateTime)day).AddDays(daysToShow).ToShortDateString());

        var diplayItems = (from x in ef1.islands
                             join y in ef1.cars on x.serid equals y.serid where x.dt==12  
                             join z in ef1.ITEMS on y.serviceno equals z.ITEMNO
                             join x2 in ef1.islands on x.serid equals x2.serid where x2.dt==8 
                             join i in ef1.INVOICES on x.carStyle equals i.carStyle where i.STATUS==8
                             where x.LiscenceDate > day && x.LiscenceDate < dayAtMidnight
                             orderby x.LiscenceDate, y.serviceno, x.serid
                             select new ReturnedItem()
                             {
                                 CarOrderDate = (DateTime)x.LiscenceDate,
                                 serial = x.serid,
                                 ItemCode = y.serviceno,
                                 Description = z.Color,
                                 DateSold = (DateTime)x2.LiscenceDate,
                                 ID = i.IX_ID
                             }).Take(100).ToList();



        m.daystoshow = daysToShow;
        m.day = day;
        m.diplayItems = diplayItems;
        m.warnings = warnings;
        return View(m);
    }
```

I haven't found any other posts that describe the exact circumstances here.

1) When the site is published, it works perfectly fine from the server.

2) CPU usage goes up to 99% when running my MVC project in debug mode.

3) The problem does not happen if I publish locally.

4) This happens in both IIS and IIS Express when run from VS in Debug or Release mode.

5) It doesn't happen with other sites, just this one project so far.

6) It's a simple project, one actionresult, and one page with a table of about 200 lines, populated with a Linq query.

Is there any way for the debugger to at least show me what it's doing?

EDIT:

With further investigation, I notice that if I wait 2 minutes the CPU comes back from IIS, but THEN the Web Browser (Firefox or Chrome) takes up 99% CPU for another 2 minutes.

Comment: What kind of linq is it?  Entity Framework?  Is it 100% cpu forever?  or for a period of time?

Comment: It doesn't do it in release mode on your local computer?

Comment: It does do it in Release mode.  Sorry I didn't think to try that until you asked.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: Are you running it in release mode under the debugger? ie F5 vs Ctrl-F5?

Comment: I tried it with F5 and cntrl-F5 and it happens either way.

Comment: Try publishing to another site on your local IIS and see if the same problem exists.  Is the SQL server remote or on your local computer?

Comment: Also, are you sure that it's > 20 lines?  Maybe it's a data problem, and you just aren't hitting the problem in the first 20 lines.  Try doing multiple queries of 20 lines, incrementing the skip each time.

Comment: @Erik I changed http://localhost:1395 to http://localhost:1395/test and is still happens.  SQL Server is remote, to both my PC and the IIS server where is works.

Comment: I didn't mean to just change the url.  I mean actually publish the site, just like you do to the production server.  But do it locally.

Comment: I'm learning a lot here. :) So, when I publish it locally, the problem does not happen.  FYI, I'm also going to have to edit my post, because I just noticed that if I wait long enough (2-3 minutes), the CPU does eventually come back.

Comment: I would delete everything from your bin folder and rebuild and see if that helps.  Also, one difference, even if you build with a Release configuration, is that the web.config does not get transformed (that only happens on publish) so the debug=true does not get removed from your web.config.  Try removing that as well and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Taking debug=true out, it works fine.  Deleting the bin folder contents didn't help though.  After this debugging, I also wonder if it a problem in the view.  It seems proportional to how much is displayed on the page.

Comment: The next step would be to add debug=true to your server, if you can.. see if it happens there.

Comment: Also, what happens if you take the view out of the picture.  Just return new ContentResult("")

Comment: No problems adding <compilation debug="true"...  on the server.  Can view 4000 rows in about a second.  If I remove the for each loop that renders the HTML the problem goes away.  So if I don't use the data, the problem doesn't happen.  As if the debugger has nothing to do if that data is not rendered.  I have a simple table, tried simplifying the display as much as I can, but if I display the items, even one of the columns, the problem happens no matter what.

Comment: THis sounds like a memory issue.. make sure you're not running out of memory and swapping to disk....  Also, are you using any navigational properties in your view?  A major problem is that you are not disposing of your context.  You new it, but don't dispose it, thus it doesn't get deleted until the garbage collector runs.  The ToList() executes the EF Query, but won't execute any navigational queries.

Comment: 4000 lines?  YOu said there were only 200...

Comment: Well.. After all this, I apologize and thank you for your time, but I finally found that turning the Browser Link feature off, fixes the problem.  I read over dozens of things to try before finding this article.  It was a matter of clicking an option in the toolbar: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx  (I have VS 2013 Premium Update 2) I don't understand Browser Link, and if you can explain this to me further, it would be worth giving it the accepted answer.

Comment: Weird.  I didn't even know about this feature.  But, it appears to be a feature to allow browsers to update themselves when you make changes to the code.  My guess is that it's probably related to Web Essentials, if you have that installed, which heavily uses Browser Link.

Comment: Thanks again.  Perhaps an update might have fixed it.  If you or nobody else does, I think this should be mentioned in the solution, knowing about Browser Link sooner might save somebody a few hours of trouble.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have Web Essentials installed?  Did you update it for Update 2?  You found the solution yourself, so you should just post it as a self-answer, and mark it as answered.

Comment: I don't remember adding anything to the default installation.  I'll get more info tomorrow....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found that the solution was simply to turn off "[Browser Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx)" which was a new feature in VS 2013, after much debugging and searching.

Browser Link can be turned off in the toolbar by clicking the down arrow on the icon that looks like a refresh button.

Browser link is some way of making changes to the page in the browser itself, which seems to be CPU intensive, so doing that with a large number of elements causes the CPU to spike.

Comment: Incredible. Simply fantastic. I was being very annoyed by this fiasco. Thanks for your answer!