# BrowserLink swamps browsers with requests and eats 100% CPU

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

I've discovered that BrowserLink in Visual Studio 2013 is causing the browser to send hundreds of localhost requests per second (according to Fiddler), that leads to a very high CPU usage in Chrome and IE. As soon as I turn off BrowserLink the CPU usage dies down and works just fine.

This started happening a few days ago on a project and I can't pin down what have caused this.

I've searched about, found a few posts about this issue, but nothing better than turn BrowserLink off. And it is a very useful feature to have.

**Any idea how to fix?**

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961981/on-local-pc-iis-and-browser-maxes-out-cpu-with-large-result-set
Related MS Connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1039946

Comment: @janv8000 there are a lot of similar questions, but no good answer anywhere -(

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1039946/browserlink-causes-chrome-to-consume-100-of-a-cpu-core - apparently after update 5, it should be fixed. Other suggested uninstalling whatever update included that feature. Or - obviously - disable browser-link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785140/vs2013-permanent-cpu-usage-even-though-in-idle-mode